# get feature layer on button click

Tags: arcgis-js-api

how to get a feature layer on button click and display.

```js
S_layer = new FeatureLayer("http://localhost:6080/arcgis/rest/services/...../MapServer/0",{
         mode: FeatureLayer.MODE_SELECTION,
        outFields: ["*"]
  
         }); 

map.addLayer(S_layer);

function soil()
{
queryTask = new esri.tasks.QueryTask("http://localhost:6080/arcgis/rest/services/...../MapServer/0"); 
   var query = new esri.tasks.Query();
        query.returnGeometry = true;
        query.outFields = ["soil"];
  var name = document.getElementById("combo1").value.toString();
        query.where = "NAME = '" + name;
  <!-- queryTask.execute(query); -->
  
  S_layer.selectFeatures(query, queryTask.SELECTION_NEW, function (features) { 
   if(features[0]){
              thePoly = features[0].geometry;
              theExtent = thePoly.getExtent().expand(1.8); //Zoom out slightly from the polygon's extent
              map.setExtent(theExtent);
   }

    });
}
```

```html
<button type="button" id="btn" class = "button" class="btn-default"  onclick = soil(); >Soil</button>
   <br></br>
```

but this query does not run it gives error of "init.js:89 Error: Unable to complete operation.
    at Object.g.load".

Answer (score 0):

As I understood, you want to add a layer on button click.

Below is the code for this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no">
    <title>Hydrography - Selection mode</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://js.arcgis.com/3.21/dijit/themes/claro/claro.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://js.arcgis.com/3.21/esri/css/esri.css">
    <style>
      html, body {
        height: 100%; 
        width: 100%; 
        margin: 0; 
        padding: 0;
      }
      body {
       background-color: white; 
       overflow: hidden; 
       font-family: sans-serif;
      }
    

    </style>

    

  </head>
  <body class="claro">
    

   <br>
      Add layers- 
<button type="button" id="addWaterBodies" class = "button" >water Bodies</button>
         
         <button type="button" id="addRivers" class = "button"  >River</button>   <br> <br>
            <div id="map"  >
      </div>
<script src="https://js.arcgis.com/3.21/"></script>
    <script>
      var map;

      require([
        "esri/map", 
        "esri/dijit/editing/Editor", "esri/dijit/editing/TemplatePicker",
        "esri/tasks/GeometryService",
        "esri/layers/ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer", "esri/layers/FeatureLayer",
        "dojo/i18n!esri/nls/jsapi", "esri/config",
        "dojo/_base/array", "dojo/keys", "dojo/parser",
        "dijit/layout/BorderContainer", "dijit/layout/ContentPane",
        "dojo/domReady!"
      ], function(
        Map, 
        Editor, TemplatePicker,
        GeometryService,
        ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer, FeatureLayer,
        esriBundle, esriConfig,
        arrayUtils, keys, parser
      ) {
        parser.parse();

        
        map = new Map("map", {
          basemap: "hybrid",
          center: [-96.325, 37.855],
          zoom: 13
        });

        map.infoWindow.resize(400,300);

    function addWaterBodies(){
      var waterBodiesLayer=   map.getLayer("waterLayerId");
   if(!waterBodiesLayer){
             waterBodiesLayer = new FeatureLayer("https://sampleserver3.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/Hydrography/Watershed173811/FeatureServer/0", {
  id : "waterLayerId",
            outFields: ["*"],
          });
       map.addLayer(waterBodiesLayer);
   } else {
     alert("water bodies layer already added");
   }
    }
 
   function addRivers(){
   var riversLayer=   map.getLayer("riverLayerId");
   if(!riversLayer){
          riversLayer = new FeatureLayer("https://sampleserver3.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/Hydrography/Watershed173811/FeatureServer/1", {
          id:"riverLayerId",
          outFields: ["*"]
        });
        map.addLayer( riversLayer);
   } else {
     alert("River layer already added");
   }
   }
   
   document.getElementById("addWaterBodies").onclick = addWaterBodies;
   document.getElementById("addRivers").onclick = addRivers;
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: i have gdb of features . i have to add specific layer like i did in my code use query to select specific layer.

Comment: i am getting this error esriRequest is not a function when is used this code

Comment: dojo.require("esri.request");
  dojo.require("esri.layers.FeatureLayer");
function soilmap(esriRequest,FeatureLayer)

  esriRequest({ 
              url: "http://localhost:6080/arcgis/rest/services/........./MapServer/0/query?where=Name ='" + document.getElementById("combo1").id.toString() + "'&outFields=Soil&returnGeometry=false&orderByFields=Soil&returnDistinctValues= true&f=json",
content:{f:'json' }, handleAs:'json', callbackParamName:'callback', timeout:15000 }).then(lang.hitch(this,function(response)